# Htaccess redirect to https and www using a single RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It works as expected in the browser, redirecting all traffic to `https://www.example.com/`.

But I am using a POS system that automatically uploads products to the website and apparently this desktop app does not like more than one `RewriteRule`. It complains that it's web store is not installed.  As soon as I remove one of the rules it is happy.

So my question is:  Is there any way to consolidate that into a single `RewriteRule`?

Answer (score 0):

> ...does not like more than one `RewriteRule`.

This requirement is unusual. It's probably complaining about the multiple *redirects* when requesting `http://example.com`, rather than literally the number of `RewriteRule` directives?

This could be resolved by making sure you redirect to the canoncial URL in the first `RewriteRule` directive. So, instead of:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

You would write:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Or, to keep this "generic", without explicitly including the domain name in the `RewriteRule`, try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

#### Single `RewriteRule`

You can then extend the above so create a single `RewriteRule` for both the HTTPS and www canonicalisation. Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

For all requests that are either HTTP *or* do not start `www` then redirect to the canonical URL. The third `RewriteCond` directive is required to grab the domain (less an optional `www.` prefix) from the host. The `%1` is a backreference to the last matched *CondPattern* ie. `(.+)`. If you simply hard coded the canonical hostname in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* then you wouldn't need this third condition.